# He is an easy man to fall in love with

Tags: prepositions

I found this in CNN news today.

> He is an easy man to fall in love with.

Does this mean he is so attractive that every woman will fall in love with him or he becomes smitten with every woman he comes across?

Comment: It's easy *to fall in love with him* -> He's an easy man to *fall in love with*. Thus, your interpretation 1 is correct.

Comment: @CowperKettle, welcome back! Where you been these past couple of weeks?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang - I'm busy translating, but sometimes I come [to our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow) - you're welcome there too. I have little time for answering questions now.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I will ask again - please do not use comments for conversations. Hop into [chat] or invite someone into a chat room you've created.

Comment: @ColleenV, this had not been intended as a conversation. Simply a welcome back, like, "How are you?" Please note that I had avoided the other discussion as well by initially directing comments towards the OP, but well, you saw, what happened there :).

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Regardless, none of that is appropriate in comments. It all belongs in chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic expression is ***[fall in love](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fall-in-love)*** (with someone):

> to be very attracted to someone and begin to love them:
>
> - *They met and fell madly in love.
>     He fell in love with a young German student.
>     I thought I was falling in love.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

The sentence is:

> he is an easy man with whom to fall in love.

If you place the preposition at the end it reads:

> he is an easy man to fall in love with.

So your first assumption is correct.